# Measure-Theoretic Expectations and Density Functions

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Suppose $X$ is a real-valued random variable with a CDF $F$, and density/mass function $f$. In elementary probability theory, we often define expectations in the form:
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x f(x) \ dx;\qquad  \mathbb{E}[X] = \sum_{x \in \text{supp}(X)} x f(x) $$
depending on if $X$ is continuous or discrete, where the first case is the typical Riemann integral. In a slightly more advanced level, we might define it in terms of Riemann-Stieltjes integrals to handle both cases concisely
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \ dF(x) $$

---

In measure-theoretic probability, we start with a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and view $X : \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ as a measurable function. We then consider the push-forward measure of $\mathbb{P}$ induced by $X$, with
$$ P_X(B) := \mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\}) $$
Then expectations are defined by Lebesgue integrals
$$ \mathbb{E}[X] = \int_\Omega X(\omega) \ dP_X $$
where I interpret this integral in terms of the supremum of simple functions that are bounded above by $X$.

---

Why does the measure-theoretic definition imply the typical definitions? In particular, I'm a bit confused about the equivalence when here we are integrating over $\Omega$-space, but in the first case we are integrating over $\mathbb{R}$. (I'm aware that Lebesgue integrals are a weaker notion in that it implies Riemann integrability, so let's assume $X$ is Lebesgue integrable)

Furthermore, where does the notion of a density/mass function $f$ come from? (In the Riemann-Stieltjes case, $f = F'$ which makes sense, but I'm not sure about the Lebesgue integral case.)

Comment: These basic concepts are explained in any book on measure theoretic probability. Eg:  K L Chung

Comment: The equation $$\mathbb{E}[X]=\int_\Omega X(\omega)d\mathbb{P}_X$$ is not correct.  You can do a $d\mathbb{P}$ integral on $\Omega$ or a $d\mathbb{P}_X$ integral over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Ah I see, I misunderstood the push-forward measure. So could I intuitively think of this as: first we view $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}, P_X)$ as a probability space, where $\mathcal{B}$ are Borel sets. Then $P_X$ is the push-forward measure **defined on** $\mathcal{B}_{\mathbb{R}}$ (not $\mathcal{F}$), in which case $P_X = F_X$, and then we obtain the Riemann-Stieltjes integral over $\mathbb{R}$ hence the typical definitions?

I'll be sure to check out some of the technical nuances in a book.

Comment: Exactly. The law $\mathbb{P}_X$ gives the same integrals as the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals $dF_X$. On the other hand, if $F:\mathbb{R}\to[0,1]$ is a right continuous, non-decreasing function with $\lim_{x\to -\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$, then the Lebesgue-Stieltjes integrals defines a probability measure on $\mathcal{B}_\mathbb{R}$ given by $\mathbb{P}(A)=\int_A dF(x)$ for Borel $A$. Then the identity function $f(x)=x$ has law $\mathbb{P}$.

Comment: For probability density functions, I recommend looking up Radon-Nikodym derivatives. If $\mu,\nu$ are two measures on the measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ such that $\nu(A)=0\Rightarrow \mu(A)=0$, then there exists a Radon-Nikodym derivative (a measurable function), denoted $d\mu/d\nu$, such that $$\mu(A)=\int_A \frac{d\mu}{d\nu}d\nu.$$  The condition above on $\mu,\mu$ is that $\mu$ is **absolutely continuous with respect to** $\nu$. The law $\mathbb{P}_X$ is absolutely continuous wrt Lebesgue measure iff $F_X$ is continuous, and the density is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.